# CSS / jquery move centered div from centered location to top left of window

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I'm hoping someone can help with this problem!

I have a logo in a page centered div that is split into 2 different images so I can have them animate in from different directions and overlay to look like one complete logo:Job done.

I then have a button which, when clicked, will make itself, as well as the 2 images and the logo title image disappear and replace it with a single logo image. That works fine and is still centered on the page.

What I'm looking to do is animate the single logo image that comes in from the centre of the page to the top left of the page. The animation works well with the image itself, just not with the div so it looks quite messy. I've had a go at messing with the jquery but can't quite seem to get it! Could anyone shed some light on this? I have a benched example here: http://endframe.saturn-global.com/

Many thanks for any advice!

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/estyle.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="logo">
    <div class="logocontainer">
      <img class="logoE" src="img/logoE.png" alt="Logo Letter E">
      <img class="logoF" src="img/logoF.png" alt="Logo Letter F">
      <img class="thelogo" src="img/thelogo.png" alt="Endframe Logo">
    </div>
    <div class="logotitle">
    <img src="img/logotitle.png" alt="Logo Title">
    </div>
    <div class="beginbutton">
    <button class="btn beginbtn">Let's Begin!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
 <div class="content" style="opacity:0;color:#000;margin-top:200px;padding:20px;">
 some content
</div> 

</div>

<script src="assets/ejs.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$('.beginbutton').click(function() {
    $("body").css("background","#ffffff");
    $(".beginbtn").css("opacity","0");
    $(".logoE").css("opacity","0");
    $(".logoF").css("opacity","0");
    $(".logotitle").css("opacity","0");
    $(".content").css("opacity","1");   
    $(".thelogo").css(
    {
    "opacity" : "1",
    "left" : "0",
    "margin" : "0 auto",
    }   
    );
    $(".logo").css(
    {
    "top" : "0",
    "left" : "0",
    "bottom" : "auto",
    "right" : "auto",
    "text-align:" : "left",
    "margin" : "0 auto",
    });
})
</script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script></body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000;
    color:#fff;
    transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .6s ease-in-out;
}

.logo {
    position:fixed;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    text-align:center;
    transition: 3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}

.logocontainer {
    width:100px;
    margin:auto;
    text-align:center;
}

.logocontainer img {
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    margin:auto;
}

img.logoE {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    animation:logoEanim 4s;
    -webkit-animation:logoEanim 4s;
    -moz-animation:logoEanim 4s;
}

img.logoF {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    padding-top:1.8em;
    padding-left:1.8em;
    animation:logoFanim 4s;
    -webkit-animation:logoFanim 4s;
    -moz-animation:logoFanim 4s;
}

img.thelogo {
    position:absolute;
    z-index:3;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-50px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 3s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes logoEanim {
    from {left:-100%;opacity:0;}
    to {left:50%;opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes logoEanim {
    from {left:-100%;opacity:0;}
    to {left:50%;opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes logoFanim {
    from {left:200%;opacity:0;}
    to {left:50%;opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes logoFanim {
    from {left:200%;opacity:0;}
    to {left:50%;opacity:1;}
}

.logotitle {
    margin-top:100px;
    animation: etitle 5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: etitle 5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: etitle 5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.logotitle img {
    width:280px;
    height:50px;
    padding:10px 10px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes etitle {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    55% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes etitle {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    55% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

.beginbtn {
    position:relative;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.8em;
    padding:3px 10px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    border-radius:10px;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    box-shadow: -2px 2px rgba(153,206,255,1);
}

.beginbutton {
    animation: beginanim 6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation: beginanim 6s ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation: beginanim 6s ease-in-out;
}

.beginbtn:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
}

@-webkit-keyframes beginanim {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    60% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

@keyframes beginanim {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    60% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}

.beginbtn:hover {
}

.beginbtn:focus {
    box-shadow:none;
}

.beginbtn:active {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you are changing from auto to 0 values in the $('.logo').css, when you do that no animation is applied as the browser doesn't know how to interpolate from the actual position to the next one. You should do something using actual numeric values. Try this:

```
$(".logo").css(
   {
      "top" : "calc(-100vh + 340px)",
      "left" : "calc(-100vw + 300px)",
      "bottom" : "auto",
      "right" : "auto",
      "text-align:" : "left",
      "margin" : "0 auto",
   }
);
```

Comment: I'm understanding where you're coming from with this, only when I try implementing this the div still just jumps to the top left of the page and then with the new position moves the logo off and to the top left :/

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using a left and top of 50% with the image outside if the logo div and the animation worked with the left and top of 0 so all good! Thanks Carlos ror the suggestion!